# UIAlert View crashes in iOS 6 while working fine on iOS 7 device

Tags: ios, uialertview

I want an alert in my project but there is an problem that when i run this code in iOS 6 device it crashes. This is my code for alert   given below:

```
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
    message:@"Are You Sure  Want To Exit"  
    delegate:nil 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"No" 
    otherButtonTitles: @"Yes", nil];
    [alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES ];
```

And it crashes with following exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Requesting the window of
>   a view () with a nil
>   layer. This view probably hasn't received initWithFrame: or
>   initWithCoder:.'

I am not getting what is the exactly issue i have tried set delegate self or nil but nothing worked .

Comment: Why are you not just doing `[alert show];`? Is this on a background thread?

Comment: did you try [alert show] 

instead of 

[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES ];

Comment: yes i have  tried [alert show] but it crash then i tried this.

Comment: Where are you showing this from? In the comments to the answer below you indicate it is being shown when navigating from one view to another. What method is it being shown it, if its in something like `viewWillAppear` it makes sense you are getting this error because the view for the viewController hasn't been shown yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is with the view you are calling alert to appear is not initialised with frame rect, Could you please tell where you are calling it to appear

Comment: In a view controller when i click on back button of navigation bar to go on back view it shows me alert and on click event of bar button i initialize  alert and show it and this is working in iOS 7 but crashes in 6 i don't know why??

Comment: Ok so it is because UIalertview doesn't know which view it should appear because you are navigating from that view right  I would suggest make the Alert appear on that backbutton action and on click event of alert navigate to next page or else perform a separate thread action to initialise and show the alert

Comment: put this in back action [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
add seperate function like this -(void)showAlert
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                       message:@"Are You Sure  Want To Exit"
                                      delegate:nil
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                             otherButtonTitles: @"Yes", nil];
    [alert show ];
}

Comment: i tried your code but don't get any success. and i am navigating from that view after click ok button of alert but there is problem with showing alert.